# What are the software for translation on Mac?

Tags: software

I want to translate a long text and I am looking for a software that shows the text and the translation I write at the same time, in two windows and with possibly a synchronization. Does it exist? Otherwise, what are the existing softwares and what do they do ?

---

PS: I want to translate a 250 page book... I am not looking for a software that does the translation, but for an nice interface where I can do the translation.

Comment: Have you tried https://translate.google.com ?

Comment: I want to translate a 250 page book... I am not looking for a software that does the translation, but for an nice interface where I can do the translation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about professional translation tools (rather than machine transation sites), there is a useful survey that includes some for Mac at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation

Also can ask on the list devoted to Mac pro translators

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/MacLingua/info

(Relying on machine translation inevitably involves substantial risks of potentially embarassing errors, I recommend that the results should always be edited by a pro or native speaker)

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://www.acetools.net/ and it works pretty good.   It has pretty basic text editing.   Also Microsoft Word can translate up to 400 words at a time via its reference tools.

Answer (score -1):

Try Overspot - https://www.redactry.com/overspot
Really good translation app for macOS.

Comment: Could you expand your answer demonstrating this software being used to solve the problem of translating *long* text live, and ‘in two windows and with possibly a synchronization’?

Answer (score -4):

I find that Google Translate, free online at https://translate.google.com/ is the best I have used.

Comment: How does this work for a 250 pages book?

Comment: You failed to read the question, where it says "I am not looking for a software that does the translation".  You should delete this answer as it does not properly reflect your expertise.